# Android output is showing editable text

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
    package com.ricky.Amnestyapp;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class EditDiseasesActivity extends Activity {

       EditText txtName;
       EditText txtPrice;
       EditText txtDesc;
       EditText txtCreatedAt;


       String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_diseases);



        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditDiseasesActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
               txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
               txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
               txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
               txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
              txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
              txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
     } }
```

I have tried to make EditText to TextView but in that case programme stopped running.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input Name -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <!-- Price Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input Price -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    <!-- Description Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

    <!-- Input description -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="top"/>



    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I show the output just as textview. Please help me get rid from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to edit text in inputPrice just change it to TextView EWERYWHERE. What is a problem to do so?

Comment: NO It's not worked,I tried as i mentioned on my question. Thanks for your question. Is there any other suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) instead of EditText

Comment: NO It's not worked,I tried as i mentioned on my question. Thanks for your question. Is there any other suggestion please.

Comment: Did you set it as TextView in the layout as well? (edit_diseases)

Answer (score 0):

What is not working? Post your code with an error message.

Just use the TextView as answered before:

```
package com.ricky.Amnestyapp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditDiseasesActivity extends Activity {

   TextView txtName;
   TextView txtPrice;
   TextView txtDesc;
   EditText txtCreatedAt;


   String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php";


// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_diseases);



    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();


}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditDiseasesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
           txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
           txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
           txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                    // display product data in TextView
           txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
          txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
          txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
 } }

 //LAYOUT:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Product Name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input Name -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/inputName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<!-- Price Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Price"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input Price -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<!-- Description Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input description -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:lines="4"
    android:gravity="top"/>



</LinearLayout>
```